# Missing AACS configuration file" error when playing blueray movies

Tags: vlc, 20.10, blu-ray

I'm on ubuntu 20.10, and I keep getting this error code whenever I try to play a bluray movie in VLC media player

```
Missing AACS configuration file
```

I don't know what to do, and I was wondering if anyone has encountered this problem and how to fix it, thanks

Answer (score 15):

The AACs file is a list of Disk Identifiers and Decryption Keys needed to play Blurays. Normally you buy a piece of software that will have its own list, but because these are all proprietary you can use community constructed AACs lists instead. The Arch Linux wiki has an [extensive page](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Blu-ray) covering different decryption methods.

You can play Blurays in VLC through the following steps

1. Install the required libraries
   `sudo apt install libaacs-dev libbluray2`
2. Download the [KEYDB.cfg file](http://fvonline-db.bplaced.net/fv_download.php?lang=eng). More info on this [site](http://fvonline-db.bplaced.net/).
3. Extract the .ZIP file
4. Inside the keydb_eng folder is `keydb.cfg` rename this to `KEYDB.cfg` (It's case sensitive.) and move it into `~/.config/aacs` (You might need to create this folder manually if it doesn't exist.)
5. Open VLC and try to open the disk. If the decryption key is known and present in the database then it should work fine, otherwise if it's a very recent Bluray you can download a new copy of the database at a later date and hope someone has added the decryption key for your disk.

**If you're using the Snap version of VLC:**

If using the Edge candidate of the VLC snap this will work fine, otherwise there's [a bug](https://code.videolan.org/videolan/vlc/-/issues/28017) where it looks in the wrong place for the AACs file right now. Simply copy the `KEYDB.cfg` into `~/snap/vlc/x1/.config/aacs/` and it will work.

```
cp ~/.config/aacs/KEYDB.cfg ~/snap/vlc/x1/.config/aacs/
```

If you implemented this workaround and you're now switching to a version of VLC where the bug is fixed, then you should remove `~/snap/vlc/x1/.config/aacs/KEYDB.cfg` and ensure the KEYDB.cfg file is inside `~/.config/aacs/`.

Comment: worth noting the KEYDB.cfg site is throwing a 404, assuming they got taken down perhaps?

Comment: @Eman I guess their website went down, as some point a new link will probably be provided [here](https://forum.doom9.org/showthread.php?t=172472&page=30)

Comment: Excellent answer, TY! If anyone is interested, this also fixes a similar issue with HandBrake.

Comment: The website is back now. The instructions also work for  playing a Blu Ray with `mpv` via `mpv bd://[title][/device] --bluray-device=PATH`. You don't need to install `libbluray2` (Kubuntu 23.04), only `libaacs-dev` and make the `~/.config/aacs` directory before copying.

Comment: VLC 3.0.18 throws the error even though `~/.config/aacs/KEYDB.cfg` (hardcoded in [libaacs](https://code.videolan.org/videolan/libaacs/-/blob/master/src/file/keydbcfg.c#L35)) is present. The library and its tools works, playback with `mpv blueray:// --bluray-device=/media/<user>/<title>` is possible.

Comment: @handle are you using the snap installation of VLC? If so please try the new workaround

Answer (score 0):

I think libaacs0 is using aacskeys for validate info. However since makemkv emulate the library it should not be installed as aacskeys has been removed from depots years ago.