# Playing blu-ray in VLC gets Missing AACS configuration file!

Tags: vlc, blu-ray

Following the answer here: [Missing AACS configuration file" error when playing blueray movies](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1325752/missing-aacs-configuration-file-error-when-playing-blueray-movies) but am still getting the exact same error.

Ran with logging:

```
keydbcfg.c:680: No valid AACS configuration files found
aacs.c:121: No usable AACS libraries found!
dec.c:197: aacs_open() failed: -2!
```

It would have been nice if they had put the file they were looking for in the log...

Anyway, I have placed the file in .config/aacs/KEYDB.cfg and sym linked it to snap/vlc/current/.config/aacs/KEYDB.cfg.

Not sure what to do next.

Comment: This [has been an issue for years](https://github.com/netblue30/firejail/issues/3682). There are some hacks to get around it, but they're all so ... hacky and disc-specific, meaning you'd have to do the same hacky thing with each BluRay disc you want to watch. Some people opt to use MakeMKV to convert BluRays to `.mkv` files, which seems to get around this issue, but can be legally questionable if the disc is a rental or borrowed from someone 